# Редактирование app.config для WCF службы

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

Разбираюсь с `WCF`. Во время обращения к методу клиента вылетает `Exception`. Что именно я не правильно делаю?

> The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element.

Файл `app.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="NewBehavior0">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="NewBehavior0" name="Server.NetworkExplorer">
        <endpoint address="ws" binding="wsHttpBinding" name="wsEndpoint"
           contract="Server.INetworkExplorer" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" name="mexEndpoint"
            contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:8082/NetworkExplorer/tcp" binding="netTcpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="myBasicBinding" name="tcpEndpoint" contract="Server.INetworkExplorer" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8084/NetworkExplorer" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
   <bindings>
        <netTcpBinding>
            <binding name="myBasicBinding" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="128" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
            </binding>
        </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

**UPDATE.** Добавляю службу в клиент через `AddServiceReference`. Посмотрев `app.config` в клиенте и добавив вручную строчку `maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"` все заработало. Но почему эта строчка не подтянулась сама?

Comment: А вы по http или по net-tcp со службой соединяетесь?

Comment: @PavelMayorov, net-tcp службой соединяюсь.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, Добавляю службу в клиент через `AddServiceReference`. Посмотрев `app.config` в клиенте и добавив вручную строчку `maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"` все заработало. Но почему эта строчка не подтянулась сама?

Answer (score 1):

> Но почему эта строчка не подтянулась сама?

Возможно ли, что настройки были подтянуты на сторону клиента до того, как на стороне сервера был добавлен/исправлен параметр maxReceivedMessageSize?

Если на стороне сервера меняются параметры службы, то на стороне клиента настройки нужно подтягивать заново.

Comment: Нет, настройки были подтянуты после изменения 'app.config'. Это было проверено не один раз.